# IIS 7.5 website physical path reverts from UNC to drive letter when project opened in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-7.5

I am running an ASP.NET site using IIS 7.5 running on my local machine (Windows 7). The directory for the website is stored on a network drive (Windows Server 2003).

In IIS Manager, if the website physical path is set to

> N:\Path\To\Website\Directory

running the site returns an IIS error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

If the physical path is changed to the UNC path

> \\Servername\Path\To\Website\Directory

the site works as expected.

The problem is that when the project is opened in Visual Studio, the physical path in IIS reverts from the UNC path to the drive letter.